# Can in this passive tense structure the topic be the same as the performer of the action?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-は, passive-voice

I've been skimming through Minna no Nihongo and I found this structure:

> [N1は]...[N2に]...[N3を]...「Vpassive]

And I understand the example sentence given with it:

> 私は弟にパソコンを壊されました。

They say that N1 is annoyed or troubled by what happens to N3.

Then I encountered this sentence in a dialogue:

> 空港で荷物を間違えられたんです

Is it possible that N1 and N2 are the same in this sentence? That the person confused their luggage and was troubled by their own actions?

Comment: No, the airport staff gave them the wrong luggage

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the N2 in that pattern is omitted, either if it is clearly understood or if the causal agent is not known or is unclear. In your sentence, N1 is understood to be the speaker, N3 is 荷物, and N2 is omitted. If you imagine that N2 is something like 荷物係 (baggage handler) then it might make more sense to you.